# How do I fix an "'int' object is not iterable" error in list function?

Tags: python, list, random, integer, iterable

Here's my code:

```
from random import random
for i in range(100):
  a = list(int(random() * 100))
  print(a)
```

and I keep getting this error message:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help me.

Comment: what are you trying to get? 100 random numbers, or the same number 100 times?

Comment: I'm trying to take 100 random numbers in a list.

Comment: Because you are converting int to list which is iterable `list(int(...))`

Answer (score 2):

In order to generate a list of 100 random numbers between 0 and 99, you'll have to either create the list first:

```
from random import random

a = []
for _ in range(100):
    a.append(int(random() * 100))
```

or use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
from random import random

a = [int(random() * 100) for _ in range(100)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown your expected output, but I presume you're looking for

```
from random import random
for i in range(100):
  a = [int(random() * 100)]
  print(a)
```

Comment: What are the brackets for? This is not creating a list of 100 random numbers, but 100 list of one number each one.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert a type `int` to type `list`, which cannot be done. If you want to add your random number multiplied by `100` you can do the following.

```
from random import random
random_numbers = []
for i in range(100):
  random_numbers.append(int(random() * 100))
```

Comment: It doesn't work, because I want one list.

Comment: I didn't understand from your question that you wanted to create list of random numbers, updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to take 100 random numbers in a list.

You need to create a list and append the generated random numbers into it:

```
import random

a = []
for i in range(100):
    a.append(int(random.random() * 100))
print(a)
```

Note that you can also simply use `random.randint`:
(use `random.randrange(0, 100)` or `random.randint(0, 99)` if you don't want to include 100 as a possibility)

```
import random

a = []
for i in range(100):
    a.append(random.randint(0, 100))
print(a)
```

And you can simplify the whole thing by using a list comprehension:

```
import random

a = [random.randint(0, 100) for __ in range(100)]
print(a)
```

(Using `__` here as an ignored variable.)

Answer (score 0):

we can use random.sample(...) to get the numbers. sample() has 2 arguments: population or iterable, k= defines the number of samples we wanted to get.

sample() does not create duplicates! if duplicates are allowed, we can also use choices() instead.

```
from random import sample
nums = list(map(lambda x: x * 100,sample(range(100), k=100)))
print(nums)
```